# Stuck while using Rvest in R to extract <p> and <span> elements from a website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I've been messing around with some web scraping in R using Rvest trying to build an NBA Dashboard.  In the past I've been able to scrape the schedule pretty easily from basketball-reference.com because it's web structure is set up as an HTML table.  Recently I found there is an NBA transactions page, named
https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_transactions.html, which I want to scrape from and put that data on my dashboard.

Below is a picture of the web page, the data that I need, and it's page structure.  One can see that dates are stored in the <.span> object, and there's <.p> objects for every event that happened on that particular date.  I basically just want to extract all of that data into R into 2 main columns, turning that span data into a Date column and the p data into an Event column.

[image]

Below is some code I've got so far, reading the url, transforming it into readable html and then finding the data that i need.  I'm missing a couple of steps to get the data in the format I mentioned earlier but I don't know what they are.  I could do it the hard way of using separate & gsub to manually manipulate the data but that feels like a very tedious process that I'm looking to avoid.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

url <- paste0('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_transactions.html')
webpage <- read_html(url)

# this returns a nested list of the data i want, but i dont know what to do from there
prac5 <- webpage %>% 
  html_nodes("div#content > ul > li")

# this returns a data frame of the data i want but it's all jumbled together 
prac6 <- webpage %>% 
  html_nodes("div#content > ul > li") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Yesterday, I found a code snippet of someone trying to do something similar and they used the method below, but I haven't been able to properly adapt it to what I want.

```
bb <- html_nodes(webpage, "div#content > ul > li") %>% 
  map_df(~{
    data_frame(
      date = html_node(.x, "span") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE),
      event = html_nodes(.x, "ul > li") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)
    )
  })
```

If anyone can offer any help or insight I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, you needed `html_nodes(.x, "p")`

Here is a solution using `lapply` instead of `map`:

```
prac5 <- webpage %>% 
   html_nodes("div#content > ul > li")

dfs <- lapply(prac5, function(node) {
      date = html_node(node, "span") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)
      event = html_nodes(node, "p") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)
   data.frame(date, event)
})
answer <- bind_rows(dfs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Things will get messy if you strip out all the HTML tags as you're doing in `prac6`, so you can stop before you do that:

```
prac6 <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes("div#content > ul > li")
```

Then parse the `<span>` and `<p>` content into separate columns in a new dataframe/tibble. Since each date can contain multiple events, we create a new df per date then join them together:

```
prac7 <- lapply(prac6, function(node) {
  tibble(date = html_node(node, "span") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE),
         event = html_nodes(node, "p") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE))
})

prac8 <- bind_rows(prac7)
```

This produces:

```
# A tibble: 1,796 x 2
   date               event                                                         
   <chr>              <chr>                                                         
 1 November 11, 2020  The Oklahoma City Thunder hired Mark Daigneault as Head Coach.
 2 October 31, 2020   The Houston Rockets hired Stephen Silas as Head Coach.        
 3 October 22, 2020   The New Orleans Pelicans hired Stan Van Gundy as Head Coach.  
 4 October 20, 2020   The Indiana Pacers hired Nate Bjorkgren as Head Coach.        
 5 October 20, 2020   The Los Angeles Clippers hired Tyronn Lue as Head Coach.      
 6 October 15, 2020   Daryl Morey resigns as GM for Houston Rockets.                
 7 October 15, 2020   The Houston Rockets appointed Rafael Stone as GM.             
 8 October 3, 2020    The Philadelphia 76ers hired Doc Rivers as Head Coach.        
 9 September 28, 2020 The Los Angeles Clippers fired Doc Rivers as Head Coach.      
10 September 22, 2020 The Chicago Bulls hired Billy Donovan as Head Coach.          
# ... with 1,786 more rows
...
```